# Why service is killed in Asus tablets and works fine in samsung

Tags: android, service

I create a service to works in the background when my app is killed by the user and it works fine in Samsung tablet but on my Asus tablet is killed when I close my app!
but google services are works in my Asus tablet this is my code:

```
public class InternetService extends Service {

      public static final int notify = 1000;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 5 Minute)
      private Handler mHandler = new Handler();   //run on another Thread to avoid crash
      private Timer mTimer = null;    //timer handling

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
          mTimer.cancel();
        else
          mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTimer.cancel();    //For Cancel Timer
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      //class TimeDisplay for handling task
      class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // run on another thread
          mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              G.AppsList.clear();
              populateDataFromServer();
              Log.i("SERVICES", "SERVICE");
            }
          });
        }
      }
}
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="androidmarket.ehsan.com.androidmarket">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>

    <application
        android:name="project.utils.G"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name="project.activity.ActivityStartup">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="project.activity.ActivityApplicationsList">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="project.activity.ActivityApplicationDetail">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="project.activity.ActivityInternet">

        </activity>

        <service android:name="project.service.InternetService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is very important for me,Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Could you add your manifest code for that service?

Comment: I added this codes now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Asus Zenfone Max 3 as my personal phone and i also use it when i'm developing apps. This pre-installed [Mobile Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.mobilemanager&hl=en) app by Asus is actually stopping whatever is running in the background. Just disable this in the app's settings. [Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbj5p.jpg)

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help :)